# Is this a correct way to access, update and save mongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb

To give some context --
I am making a bug tracker application and using MongoDB for data storage. I need to update a single value in a document - the status of a bug. My 'bug' object is being stored in mongoDB. Currently, I am retrieving the document/object/bug via its ID value. I am then updating the object through the JVM and resaving/overwriting the entire original document/bug so that it now contains the updated status. While this works I am unsure if this is the 'professional' way of updating data in MongoDB. thank you in advance for your advice/opinion.

```
@PutMapping("/{bugID}/{status}")
public Bug setBugStatus(@PathVariable String projectID, @PathVariable String bugID, @PathVariable String status) {
    return bugService.setBugStatus(projectID, bugID, status);
}

public Bug setBugStatus(String projectID, String bugID, String status) {
    Project project = getProjectByID(projectID);
    Bug bug = project.getBugQueue().findBugByID(bugID);
    
    if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("solved")) {
        bug.setStatusSolved();
        
    } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("inprogress")) {
        bug.setStatusInProgress();
        
    } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("unsolved")) {
        bug.setStatusUnsolved();
    }

    mongoTemplate.save(project);
    return bug;
}


private Project getProjectByID(String projectID) {
    return mongoTemplate.findById(projectID, Project.class);
}
```

---

This is what a document looks like:

```
{
"projectID": "1",
"title": "Amazon",
"description": "An online ECommerce store.",
"dateCreated": "Mon Sep 14 01:18:40 IST 2020",
"timestamp": "14-09-2020 01:18:40",
"bugQueue": {
    "priorityQueue": [
        {
            "priority": 10,
            "bug": {
                "bugID": "1",
                "dateCreated": "Mon Sep 14 01:18:40 IST 2020",
                "dateResolved": null,
                "title": "Order processing failed.",
                "bugDescription": "Orders are not being processed after 9.32pm.",
                "status": "Unsolved",
                "discoveredBy": null,
                "solutionDescription": null,
                "bugProgressReportList": {
                    "reportsList": []
                },
                "bugAssignedToList": {
                    "employeeList": []
                },
                "priority": "Highest"
            }
        }
    ],
    "empty": false
},
"employeeList": {
    "employeeList": [
        {
            "employeeID": "2",
            "firstName": "Alex",
            "secondName": "Wands"
        },
        {
            "employeeID": "3",
            "firstName": "Alice",
            "secondName": "Black"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do, eg : using repository, using queries. This is also fine

Comment: @varman Great thank you for your answer - a little piece of mind can go a long way!